# Как перенести данные из одной БД в другую с другими названиями таблиц и другой структурой (Django-framework PostgreSQL)?

Tags: django, postgresql

**Здравствуйте!**

Есть проект на Django, его переделали, и, соответственно, названия таблиц и сама "структура" БД изменилась (База данных **PostgreSQL**).

Так вот, в старом проекте очень много данных в БД, но всё это просто так не скопировать. Я искал решение и нашёл только резервное копирование и перенос на другой сервер (PostgreSQL или MySQL). То есть, грубо говоря, копирование.

**Нужно найти такой способ переноса данных, чтобы проводились ассоциации одних таблиц и ячеек с другими из одной БД в другой. Может можно сделать какой-нибудь скрипт?**

Надеюсь, что понятно объяснил. Заранее спасибо)

Comment: А что мешает действительно дампнуть таблицы и распаковать в другом месте? Вообще, если нужно прям сделать соответствие, то руками можно прописать такие модели, как мне кажется

Comment: Ну я думаю насчёт скрипта по следующему алгоритму:  будет некий api на сайте, а у себя на компе с помощью python я буду по порядку доставать данные из файла резервной копии БД (.sql) и отправлять POST-запрос через python-requests, содержащий все данные объекта.